# Is there anyway to make log function?

Tags: swift, inline

I want to print `#file`, `#function` and `#line` with one method.

I tried the below code but problem is here.
Wherever I call `logm()`, it always prints information of `logm` method itself even I declared it as `@inline`.

```
@inline(__always) func logm(items: Any...) {
    if let f = #file.componentsSeparatedByString("/").last {
        print("[\(f)][\(#function)][\(#line)]:", items)
    } else {
        print("[\(#function)][\(#line)]: ", items)
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to implement this kind of thing? Why does `@inline` work as I expected?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/xmzio/fccd29fc945de7924b71

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question because the original, "Macros in Swift?", isn't particularly detailed or similar to this question. The answers may be similar, but the context is different.

Comment: @jtbandes Thanks. I still want to know why `@inline` didn't work as I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the file, line, and function as parameters with the directives as default values:

```
func logm(items: Any..., file: String = #file, line: Int = #line, function: String = #function) {
    if let f = file.componentsSeparatedByString("/").last {
        print("[\(f)][\(function)][\(line)]:", items)
    } else {
        print("[\(function)][\(line)]: ", items)
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, the varidic parameter `items` would have to be the first one, otherwise you wouldn't be able to use the default values.

Comment: Thanks @Sulthan, I updated my answer. @trick14, the default values allow you to call `logm` without explicitly passing those parameters.